# Python scripting for XBMC

Tags: python, screen-scraping, xbmc

I am new to programming and to Python itself. I have no programming experience. I have managed to read up on Python and done some fairly basic Python tutorial, now I am ready for my first project in Python.

I am basing my project around XBMC, I want to develop some addons for this awesome media center.

I have a few websites that I want to scrape and display in XBMC. One is a [music website](http://www.im1music.net)  and one is a [payed TV website](http://www.isky.co.nz) which is only available to people with accounts with them. I have managed to scrape a website with `feedparse` but I have no idea how to output these titles and links to play in XBMC.

My question here is: where do I start, how do I construct the script for these websites, what tools/libraries/modules do I need. And what do I need to do to include it into XBMC.

Answer (score 2):

On the general topic that has been asked a ton of times regarding webpage scraping, the common answer is always Mechanize/Beautiful Soup for python. That would allow you to actually get your data.

Once you have your data, its then just a matter of formatting it the way you want, for your xbmc app: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO:Write_Python_Scripts_for_XBMC

Its a two step process.

1. Get your data from a source and format it into some common structure
2. Use the common structure to populate your elements in the xbmc script

What you actually want to do with your script will determine how you would use your data. If its just simply providing information, then that link above would pretty much explain it.